# python subprocess not calling correctly

Tags: python

I am trying to start a ffmpeg subprocess

the following command works perfectly

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -r 16000 -i hw:2,0 -f video4linux2 -s 800x600 -i /dev/video0 -r 30 -f avi -vcodec mpeg4 -vtag xvid -qscale 0 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 96k /home/Desktop/output.avi
```

when I try this

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-f alsa', '-r 16000', '-i hw:2,0', '-f video4linux2', '-s 800x600', '-i /dev/video0', '-r 30', '-f avi', '-vcodec mpeg4', '-vtag xvid', '-qscale 0', '-acodec libmp3lame', '-ab 96k', '/home/Desktop/output.avi')])
```

I get this error

```
Unrecognized option 'f alsa'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error states:

```
Unrecognized option 'f alsa'.
```

So each argument needs to be it's own array element:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-f', 'alsa', '-r', '16000', ....
```